# Access Sharepoint from a Worker role service running on Azure

Tags: c#, azure, sharepoint, azure-worker-roles

I need to update some information on Sharepoint when some information changes in another system. The way I'm doing this (I didn't get to choose, but rather the company) is:
1. When the event occurs in the other system, I send a message to an Azure ServiceBus queue:

```
QueueClient queueClient = QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString, "authors");  
BrokeredMessage message = new BrokeredMessage();  
message.ContentType = "Authors";  
message.Properties["FirstName"] = FirstName;  
// set other properties  
try {  
    queueClient.Send(message);  
}  
catch (Exception e) {  
    Logger.Error("Authors Windows Azure notification service fail.", e);  
}  
finally {
    queueClient.Close();
}
```

This part works fine.
2. I created a WorkerRole to read the ServiceBus, process the message, and post the information in Sharepoint (I simplified the actual code a bit):

```
BrokeredMessage receivedMessage = Client.Receive(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
if (receivedMessage != null && receivedMessage.ContentType == "Authors")
{
    Uri uri = new Uri(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("Sharepoint.Uri"));
    Office365ClaimsHelper claimsHelper = new Office365ClaimsHelper(uri, CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("Sharepoint.User"),                            CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("Sharepoint.Password"));
    using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext(uri))
    {
        context.ExecutingWebRequest += claimsHelper.clientContext_ExecutingWebRequest;
        AuthorWrapper author = GetAuthorFromMessage(receivedMessage);                
        string title = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("Sharepoint.ListName");
        List authorsList = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(title);
        context.Load(authorsList);
        context.ExecuteQuery(); // THIS LINE
        // do some other stuff, including adding the author to the list
     }
     receivedMessage.Complete();
}
```

When I ran the WorkerRole locally (using Microsoft Azure Emulator), everything worked perfectly and the information got updated in Sharepoint.
However, when I Published the WorkerRole in Azure, it didn't work (it read the message from the ServiceBus, but didn't update Sharepoint). I used [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ff683670.aspx) to debug the the Worker role that's running in Azure, and I found that a 403 Forbidden exception rose when I tried to retrieve the list from Sharepoint (see commented line "THIS LINE").
It's the EXACT SAME CODE, running locally works fine, running in Azure raises this exception!

Notes: the Office365ClaimsHelper class is from [github](https://github.com/tristian2/ADtoSharePointOnlineData)
I already tried [this](http://stevemannspath.blogspot.com.uy/2013/02/windows-azure-accessing-your-sharepoint.html), but it's not my case (I use Cloud Service not Virtual Machine).
The WorkerRole is targeting .Net 4.0 (again, not my choice)

I tried to put the most significant code, but if you need something more let me know, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

So the crux of this problem is that you get a 403 when hitting Sharepoint O365. http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E403.html tells us that a HTTP 403 error indicates (my emphasis):

> The Web server (running the Web site) thinks that the HTTP data stream
>   sent by the client (e.g. your Web browser)
>   was correct, but access to the resource identified by the URL **is
>   forbidden for some reason**.
>
> This indicates a **fundamental access problem**, which may be difficult to
>   resolve because the HTTP protocol allows the Web server to give this
>   response without providing any reason at all. So the 403 error is
>   equivalent to a blanket 'NO' by the Web server - with no further
>   discussion allowed.

Although your code (binaries) might be the same on your local dev machine and in the Cloud Service, *your configuration might not be the same*.

Can you therefore check that you have the same configuration values in your Cloud Service's **ServiceConfiguration.Local.cscfg** and **ServiceConfiguration.Cloud.cscfg**, specifically the **Sharepoint.Uri** and **Sharepoint.ListName** values.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I upvoted but did not tick it because the issue was another thing. I deleted the service from Azure, changed for all references Copy Local = true (not sure if this is correct, I'm going to ask a new question about this), packaged the WorkerRole before deploying and (still not sure why) there it worked...

Comment: Ah, the mysterious 'I poked it with a stick' and now it works trick!

Comment: Haha exactly! FYI, here is the question I mentioned http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32785383/when-should-copylocal-be-set-to-true-on-cloud-services